# Error creating bean with name 'swagger2Controller': Lookup method resolution failed

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

[image: image preview]while implementing swagger in my project i am facing this issue.

here is my build.gradle file and my swagger config file.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableWebMvc
public class MisToolSwaggerConfig {
@Beanpublic Docket api() {
return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select() .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("co.oasys.mis.tool.restapi")).paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
```

when i run my application this error is showing

Comment: pls check the image link for the error

Comment: Please, post error messages as text.

Answer (score 0):

**For Spring Boot 3**

```java
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
@Configuration
public class OpenAPIConfig {

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI registrationOpenAPI() {
        return new OpenAPI()
                .info(new Info().title("Your API Title")
                        .description("Your API Description")
                        .version("1.0"));
    }
}
```

```yaml
#OpenAPI Properties
springdoc:
  api-docs:
    path: /api-docs
  swagger-ui:
    path: /swagger-ui.html
    enabled: true
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try to add this line to your application.properties

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy = ANT_PATH_MATCHER
```

And this is an example of a working swagger configuration file

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfiguration {
    private static final String TITLE = "Flight API";
    private static final String DESCRIPTION = "Descripcion API Flight";
    private static final String BASE_PACKAGE = "com.hiberus.flight.controller";
    private static final String VERSION = "v1";
    @Bean
    public Docket swagger() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(BASE_PACKAGE))
                .build()
                .forCodeGeneration(true)
                .apiInfo(new ApiInfoBuilder().title(TITLE).description(DESCRIPTION).version(VERSION).build());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the pom xml dependencies for this as well